# What are the inertial and non-inertial reference frame?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, inertial-frames

Taking a frame attached to Earth as inertial, which of the following objects cannot have inertial frames attached to them, and which are inertial reference frames?

1. Is the atmosphere attached to an inertial or non-inertial reference frame? Are there any visible effects this might cause when we view it?
2. If an object moving in a circle with constant speed has accelerating although speed is constant, then what will its frame of reference?

Comment: The atmosphere is not inertial, the Coriolis force plays a huge role in hurricanes for example. The second case is also non-inertial.